# Which is better Struts or Spring and Why?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a Java developer working on Swing API. I have some knowledge of JSp and Servlet.
I wanna learn a framework. I want to know which one is better, Struts or Spring.And what about Apache's wicket.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to start a war or plan to arrange a debate competition?

Comment: it's what people like. there is no 'better' way. i agree with @freak about this.

Comment: no Freak, there is nothing to start  a war or debating on this topic. i only want to know that who is better that's why I start learning that particular framework .

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to learn them for. Struts is a lot simpler, or maybe just smaller, so it might be better to start with.

Struts is a Web framework and it's usually used simply to define the Controllers and render the views, in an MVC architecture. Here's more about [MVC Architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) if you need it. So you ususally need to combine it with other frameworks, such as Hibernate and EJBs to finish off your project.

Spring is huge, it's more like an entire platform. It has all kinds of modules, but you don't have to use all of them. Spring MVC would be a good starting point and the equivalent of Struts, and from there you could pick other modules, such as Spring Security and Spring Data, to tailor to your project's needs.

Here's [more about Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework#documentation).

Comment: Thanks Pearl.I will go through Struts first.